# iOS need pop up box to appear , not sure what it is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a bit new to iOS, I would a pop up box like the one in the following image:
[image]

to appear in my app but i don’t know what it is called in iOS nor what code to write.

I tried to look through some documentation to find out more about it, but didn't find anything.

Comment: How many buttons you want.?

Comment: It's called `UIAlertView`.

Comment: I don't mind this question too much.. it's difficult to research something when you don't know what it's called.

Comment: @JamesWebster Do you honestly think that it's fair that this question has a better upvote/downvote ratio than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363801/ios-cgimagecreatewithpng-or-jpegdataprovider-causes-segmentation-fault)? Also, this is something so basic that every decent beginner tutorial should cover it. This shows that OP didn't make the effort going through such a learning resource. (Also, he could have still googled "iOS popup box class name", but apparently, he couldn't be bothered to do that either.)

Comment: Nope. It's more the close votes I was countering. I don't think it's off topic just because it's "simple"

Comment: I will concede that Googling "iOS Popup Box" would probably have been enough. I changed my mind and added to the close votes.

Comment: @JamesWebster Um okay, I thought you were referring to the downvotes. (and I concur, the "off-topic" wording is not quite appropriate here. This *is* about programming.)

Answer (score 4):

That's called a [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Here's an example of how to use it

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My alert" 
                            message:@"This is my message" 
                           delegate:self 
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                  otherButtonTitles:@"comma", @"separated", @"nil", @"terminated", nil] show];
```

Then you'll probably want to implement the method that gets called when a button is clicked:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below code:-

```
UIAlertView *aler = [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[aler show];
[aler release];
```

To add multiply buttons you can user array for buttons.